# border-image doesn't show in IE/Firefox

Tags: css

The border-image doesn't work in IE and Firefox. In Chrome and Opera everything works fine, but i can't find the mistake i made. Here is the code:

```
-moz-border-image: url(../images/background.png) 204 194 204 200 stretch repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(../images/background.png) 204 194 204 200 stretch repeat;
-o-border-image: url(../images/background.png) 204 194 204 200 stretch repeat;
 border-image: url(../images/background.png) 204 194 204 200 stretch repeat;
 border-width: 104px;
 border-style: solid;
```

Comment: Try adding the IE prefix. `-ms-border-image` for IE. This will not work for older versions. I am unsure if it works at all.

Comment: fyi, ` or ´ are NOT apostrophes. you can type the proper apostrophe using SHIFT+# (german keyboard assumed)

Comment: Thanks. The     ms-border-image was the right answer.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image